# Maping is not done propperly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, jsx, react-spring

I have the following code :

```
import { useState } from "react";

import Wheel from "../components/wheel/Wheel";
import Countdown from "../components/countdown/Countdown";
import Bets from "../components/bets/Bets";
import Input from "../components/input/Input";

import styles from "./Roulette.module.css";

const Roulette = () => {
  const [roll, setRoll] = useState(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10); 
  const [bets, setBets] = useState({ red: [{name: 'test' , amount: '400$'}],   green: [],black: []});

  const handleRoll = () => {
    setBets(true);
  }

  const countdownDone = () => {
    setRoll(false);
    setCount(true);
  };

  const rollDone = () => {
    setRoll(true);
    setCount(false);
  };

  const updateRoll = () => {
    setRoll(!roll);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.title}>ROULETTE</div>
      <Countdown count={count} done={countdownDone} />
      <Wheel roll={updateRoll} done={rollDone} />
      <Input/>
      <Bets bets={handleRoll}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Roulette;
```

And then I wanna map in the BetTable

```
import { useState } from "react";

import Wheel from "../components/wheel/Wheel";
import Countdown from "../components/countdown/Countdown";
import Bets from "../components/bets/Bets";
import Input from "../components/input/Input";

import styles from "./Roulette.module.css";

const Roulette = ({name, amount}) => {
  const [roll, setRoll] = useState(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10); 
  // const [bets, setBets] = useState({ red: [{name: 'test' , amount: '400$'}],   green: [],black: []});
  // state={
  //   red: [{name: 'test' , amount: '400$'}],
  //   green: [],
  //   black: []
  // }
  const getBets = () => {
    
      var red = [{name: 'test' , amount: '400$'}],
      var green = [],
      var black = []
    }
    return getBets();
  ]
  // const handleRoll = () => {
  //   setBets(true);
  // }

  function countdownDone() {
    setRoll(false);
    setCount(true);
  }

  const rollDone = () => {
    setRoll(true);
    setCount(false);
  };

  const updateRoll = () => {
    setRoll(!roll);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.title}>ROULETTE</div>
      <Countdown count={count} done={countdownDone} />
      <Wheel roll={updateRoll} done={rollDone} />
      <Input/>
      <Bets bets={bets}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Roulette;
```

I have tried to implement what you have seen but by checking my error on the console the mapping is not done properly and I just have a blank space.
Perhaps I was thinking of changing from const to classes and go with props. but I am sure this is not the only way

P.S I have forgot to add the BetClass as well.

```
import styles from "./Bets.module.css"; // import styles from "./Bets.module.css";

const Bets = () => {
  return(
    // <table>
    //   <tbody>
    //     <tr>
          <div className={styles.table}>
            <div className={styles.tablerow}>
              <BetTable color='RED' bets={Bets.red}/>
              <BetTable color='GREEN' bets={Bets.green}/>
              <BetTable color='BLACK' bets={Bets.black}/>
          </div>
        </div>
   
  );
};

export default Bets;
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense... `<Bets bets={handleRoll}/>` doesn't look right, should that be `<Bets bets={bets}/>`? But the `Bets` component doesn't reference `props`? You might need to create a minimal repro on CodeSandbox etc.

Comment: I have modified the new code

Answer (score 0):

Your code still doesn't make sense... eg. you've got this for `getBets()`:

```
const getBets = () => {    
    var red = [{name: 'test' , amount: '400$'}],
    var green = [],
    var black = []
}
// These two lines look like an error
return getBets();
]
```

The `return` here doesn't fit with anything, and there's an extra closing bracket that doesn't match anywhere.

If you go back to the code you have commented out:

```
const [bets, setBets] = useState({ 
  red: [{name: 'test' , amount: '400$'}],
  green: [],
  black: []
});
```

And pass `bets` to the `Bets` component:

```
<Bets bets={bets}/>
```

Then all you would have to do is fix your `Bets` component to take the `bets` as a property:

```
const Bets = ({ bets }) => {
  return(
    <div className={styles.table}>
      <div className={styles.tablerow}>
        <BetTable color='RED' bets={bets.red}/>
        <BetTable color='GREEN' bets={bets.green}/>
        <BetTable color='BLACK' bets={bets.black}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Not sure if that's what you're after; again, it's hard to help without the code/problem being clearer.